# Semantic Release - Add more sections to auto-generated release notes

Tags: javascript, semantic-release, release-notes

I've just finished setting up semantic-release for my node project and made the first release with it:

[image: Release notes]

It seems that only commits with type `fix` or `feat` are added to the release notes... I want to be able to show `improvement` type as well.

Is there a way to configure/add it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The changelog text is generated by [conventional-changelog-angular](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog/blob/master/packages/conventional-changelog-angular) by default and it's over there that the type of commit to include in the change log are determined.

See https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog/blob/master/packages/conventional-changelog-angular/writer-opts.js#L45

If you want to include other type of commit in the changelog you can create your own preset (based on `conventional-changelog-angular`) that would include all the commits type.

Alternatively you can use the [conventional-changelog-conventionalcommits](https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog/tree/master/packages/conventional-changelog-conventionalcommits) preset which support the `types` option to define new types and if they should be included in the release note.

You semantic-release config would be:

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["@semantic-release/commit-analyzer", {
      "preset": "conventionalcommits",
      "releaseRules": [
        {"type": "improvement", "release": "minor"}
      ]
    }],
    ["@semantic-release/release-notes-generator", {
      "preset": "conventionalcommits",
      "presetConfig": {
        "types": [
          {"type": "feat", "section": "Features"},
          {"type": "fix", "section": "Bug Fixes"},
          {"type": "perf", "section": "Performance Improvements"},
          {"type": "revert", "section": "Reverts"},
          {"type": "docs", "section": "Documentation", "hidden": true},
          {"type": "style", "section": "Styles", "hidden": true},
          {"type": "chore", "section": "Miscellaneous Chores", "hidden": true},
          {"type": "refactor", "section": "Code Refactoring", "hidden": true},
          {"type": "test", "section": "Tests", "hidden": true},
          {"type": "build", "section": "Build System", "hidden": true},
          {"type": "ci", "section": "Continuous Integration", "hidden": true},
          {"type": "improvement", "section": "Improvement", "hidden": false}
        ]
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

I added the `releaseRules` config for `@semantic-release/commit-analyzer` as I assume you want to create a minor releases for `improvement` commits.

Comment: What is the point of setting hidden to true? Why not just remove the entry if we want it to be hidden?

Comment: It makes sense to include to make it easier to re-activate at a later time @trallnag